# What datatype would I use to store a sha265 password in a Postgres database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Solved, thank you for those asking me what error it was:

```
pq: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe3 0xb0 0xc4
```

This meant I needed to store the password as bytea

If I want to insert a sha265 password in a Postgres database what datatype would I use. Text does not seem to be working for me.

Here is the line of code with the query

```
query := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO users(username,password) VALUES('%s','%s') returning uid;", username, hashedPassword)
```

For those wondering here is the Go code. Like I said though, it works fine as long as the password isn't encrypted so I don't think this will be of much help

```
func hashPassword(password string) string {
    h := sha256.New()
    passwordBytes := []byte(password)
    passwordHashed := h.Sum(passwordBytes)
    return string(passwordHashed)
}

func createUser(username string, password string, passwordConfirm string) bool {
    dbinfo := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
    DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", dbinfo)
    checkErr(err)
    defer db.Close()

    hashedPassword := hashPassword(password)
    hashedPasswordConfirm := hashPassword(passwordConfirm)


    if hashedPassword != hashedPasswordConfirm {
        return false
    }

    var lastInsertId int
    query := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO users(username,password) VALUES('%s',$trick$%s$trick$) returning uid;", username, hashedPassword)
    err = db.QueryRow(query).Scan(&lastInsertId)

    fmt.Println(lastInsertId)

    if err != nil {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is the table declaration

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    uid SERIAL,
    username text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password text NOT NULL,
    weekly_goals bytea,
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uid)
) WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
```

Comment: what is not working?..

Comment: When I attempt to store the username and password in the database, the database refuses to store it. I am pretty sure my query is alright considering it works if I use a non-encrypted string. Its only when I hash the password that my data gets rejected

Comment: please show the qry you use. I'm pretty sure you can use text for it

Comment: Sure I'll post it

Comment: change ` VALUES('%s','%s')` to ` VALUES('%s',$trick$%s$trick$)` ?..

Comment: Trick didnt end up working either, I posted some additional information

Comment: `text` or `varchar` should work just fine. Your problem is most probably the fact that you are concatenating values into a SQL string. I don't know Go, but there **has** to be a way to use parametrized statements ("PreparedStatements" in Java)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the alternate way to do it would be like this err = db.QueryRow("INSERT INTO users(username,password) VALUES($1,$2) returning uid;", username, password).Scan(&lastInsertId) which again works.... only if the password is unhashed

Comment: So what is the error you get?

Comment: pq: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe3 0xb0 0xc4

Comment: "refuses to store it"?  What does that mean? I'm pretty sure Postgres never says "I refuse to store that data!" It probably returns an actual error message.

Comment: The error message is: pq: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe3 0xb0 0xc4

Comment: Stop tagging this as `go`. The question has ABSOLUTELY NOTHING to do with Go.

Comment: please change username and check if the error remains. sha256 password usually is represented as hexadecimal or base64 string **both are ascii** - so the errors comes fro username I believe...